# JavaFX : Keep listening to keyboard-input and on input perform action

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have JavaFX project in which I have to listen to keyboard-input as our barcode scanner is configured that way.

Are there any libraries in JavaFX where I can keep a listener active and perform suitable action upon reception of a String by barcode-scanner.

I searched on net, but didn't find any good solution unfortunately.

Here is my code :

```
    public class Main extends Application {

        private Scene scene;
        MyBrowser myBrowser;

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            primaryStage.setTitle("Our Application");
            java.net.CookieManager manager = new java.net.CookieManager();
            java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

            myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
            scene = new Scene(myBrowser, 1080, 1920);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            primaryStage.show();


        // @ being the escape character
        scene.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                String text = event.getCharacter();
                if (text.equals("@")) {
                    String tempText = completeText;
                    completeText = "";
                    processText(tempText);
                }else {
                    completeText = completeText+text;
                }
            }
        });

        }

private void processText(String text){
        System.out.println("I will process "+text);
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }


    public class MyBrowser extends Region {

        final String hellohtml = "index.html";

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    public MyBrowser() {
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                    window.setMember("app", this);
                }
            });

            URL urlHello = getClass().getResource(hellohtml);

            webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());
            webView.setPrefSize(1080, 1920);
            webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);

            getChildren().add(webView);
        }
```

Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep a listener active"? There is no listener in your code, but if there were, what would make it become inactive?

Comment: @James_D : Because I am unable to find a listener for such events, all I can find is basic Scanner class which keeps waiting for Enter key.

Comment: Did you read any of the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/convenience_methods.htm)? Surely you just need a handler for a key event on the scene.

Comment: @James_D : I had removed the code for the listener, but I have put it again in main post. The current code where I am listening to keyEvent gives me nothing. If I change it to event.getCharacter(), then I get character by character, not the entire string. Kindly have a look.. :-)

Comment: A key handler handles a single key press (or release, or some simple combination of those). So you will need to implement the logic to piece the characters together. You presumably have other controls in your UI that you want to respond to key strokes in their usual way, so you will have to figure out a way to distinguish your barcode scanner from the actual keyboard. That logic is going to be pretty difficult. You might benefit from using the [ReactFX framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX)

Comment: @James_D : The UI is touch screen based for a Terminal, no keyboard, just the barcode machine acting like a keyboard. Just talked with my JS developer colleague as well, and he said, it's normal for UI languages to just get character by character(no UI experience). I built a function and it works, added in main post. Just one question, as you can see I am statically loading a index.html in myBrowser. After reading data from barcode, I would like to load a different html based upon the barcode-data, how can I utilize myBrowser for same task, so that there is no like white-screen or so!

Comment: That sounds like a new question: you should ask it as such (right now it's not really clear what you mean).

Comment: @WeareBorg How about using the KeyListener from the standard JDK?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: @RyanStull : Cannot add any text-fields in UI.

Comment: @WeareBorg I'm confused, what do you mean?

Comment: @RyanStull You cannot use an AWT key listener on JavaFX components.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I understand what your problem is, you have a barcode scanner that sends in barcodes as keyevents to your application,  And then you need to respond to the whole bar code when you're done receiving the code?

If that's the case you can use a [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to intercept the key press events.  Then you just need to implement the logic to put the individual key events together.

```
class MyListener implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Logic goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // Logic goes here

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Logic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this only with JavaFX classes. Check out my main post. I was looking for something where I wont get single characters when key is pressed.